# Spring Data Rest & Spring Data Envers: How to expose REST API for Repository that extends Revision Repository

Tags: java, rest, spring-data-rest

I'm having a problem to expose `RevisionRepository` (Spring Data Envers) endpoints for my repository which extends `RevisionRepository` as below :

```
    @RepositoryRestResource(path = "disciplines", itemResourceRel = "disciplines")
    public interface DisciplineRepository extends
        RevisionRepository<Discipline, Integer, Integer>,
        CrudRepository<Discipline, Integer>{

        @RestResource(path = "findByName", rel = "findByName")
        List<Discipline> findByName(String name);

    }
```

Only `findByName` method is exposed, is there any other way to expose the methods in `RevisionRepository`? I've also tried to override those methods in `DisciplineRepository` but it doesn't work.

Thank You...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to write a custom controller method to implement this, something like the following:

```
@Autowired
private DisciplineRepository disciplineRepository; 

@RequestMapping(value = "/disciplines/{id}/changes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Resource<RevisionsObject>> getDisciplineRevisions(@PathVariable(value = "id")Discipline discipline) {
    if (discipline != null) {
        Revisions<Integer, Discipline> disciplineRevisions = disciplineRepository.findRevisions(discipline.getId());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new Resource<>(disciplineRevisions), HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, eight years later there's still no other solution to solve this problem differently than **adam-p** said: you still require a custom controller.

However, I want to share my solution of a reusable controller. It must simply be extended using different entities/repositories and works out of the box.

I am open to suggestions for improvement.

- Especially I am unsure about the usage of `@RepositoryRestController` for `AddressRevisionRepository`, but neither `@Controller` nor `@RestController` worked.
- Also I'd love to omit the path on `@RepositoryRestController`, but I don't know how to automatically add the subpath.

```
// Reusable no-bean repository
@NoRepositoryBean
public class RestRevisionRepository<E, Id, Rev extends Number & Comparable<Rev>, T extends RevisionRepository<E, Id, Rev>> {
    @Autowired
    T repository;

    @GetMapping(path = "/revisions/{id}", produces = "application/hal+json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Revisions<Rev, E> getRevisions(@PathVariable(value = "id") Id id) {
        if (id != null) {
            // Converter comes from dependency "jackson-datatype-hibernate6"
            return repository.findRevisions(id);
        } else {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
        }
    }
}

// Repository for entity "Address"
@RepositoryRestResource
interface AddressRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Address, Long>, CrudRepository<Address, Long>,
        RevisionRepository<Address, Long, Long> {
}


// Implementation of revision controller for "Address"
// Endpoint "/addresses/revision/1" returns all revisions of Person with ID 1
@RepositoryRestController("/addresses")
public class AddressRevisionRepository extends RestRevisionRepository<Address, Long, Long, AddressRepository> {
}
```